# Get Spacy NER to search only for company name and not waste computing power on anything else (Using existing language models.)?

Tags: python, spacy

I'm still learning python. I'm trying to crawl websites and extract company names. I plan on using scrapy to crawl and spacy with language model to extract company name.
Code so far:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("sv_pipeline-0.0.0/sv_pipeline/sv_pipeline-0.0.0")
doc = nlp("Jag jobbade på Random Företag AB. Sedan fick jag jobbet på DenAndraFöretaget AB")
width = 15

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Output:

```
Random Företag AB ORG
DenAndraFöretaget AB ORG

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I guess if I have other "name entities" in text like actuall names and currencies it will return them as well. But all I need is company name (ORG) from text so that it doesn't process useless information. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the models to only tag one named entity.

You can ignore entities you don't care about trivially.

```
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ != "ORG": continue
    ... do stuff ...
```

You can't cut out the other entities because they aren't like separate functions, the model uses its knowledge about all the different types to help it figure out ambiguous cases, like knowing "John Smith" is a person but "John Deere" is (probably) a company.

The good news is that it is not "processing useless information" or "wasting computing power". If you trained a model to recognize just ORG entities it wouldn't be faster or anything.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe off topic but, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Maybe this will help but if not please explain. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402

Comment: I'm just looking for a efficient way to extract company name from text. I stumbled upon an article about NER and thought this must be it. Is there a better way or a simpler way to do this? EDIT: I also noticed that accuracy is not great either. I got this swedish model from git because I have no idea how to train a model and I probably don't have enough data to "feed" the model.